# Do I use a period or a question mark at the end of a statement that presents a question?

Tags: periods, question-mark

Let's say I have a statement like this:

```
I just saw you come online, and I wanted to see how your day was going.
```

Now, am I right to use the `.` at the end of that sentence? I've written it like this in the past because I thought the `.` was wrong:

```
I just saw you come online, and I wanted to see how your day was going; how's it going?
```

Is the latter more appropriate? I mean at least it asks the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the more correct choice of punctuation is the former.

When you are asking an *[indirect question](http://grammar.about.com/od/il/g/indirquesterm.htm)*, you end a sentence with a period. It is really a *declarative sentence* that reports a question, not a question itself.

Comment: However, the modern trend is to give _declarative questions_ a question mark: "You're having a good day?"